# Create dropdown on Access Form where one selection pulls from multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access database and I'm creating a dropdown list on a form to pull data. Everything is working except for one thing.

My table has a column called Type with the fields PROD and PROD-OS among others. I want my drop down to just say PROD but pull data for both PROD and PROD-OS.

Thanks for any advice. I'm using Access 2013.

Comment: SELECT tbl.Type
FROM tbl
GROUP BY tbl.Type
HAVING (((tbl.Type) Like "prod*"))
ORDER BY tbl.Type;

Comment: My comment above is the SQL that I'm currently using for my query which at least gives me just PROD and PROD-OS in my drop down rather than all the other stuff in that column.

Comment: Please put information that is related to the question **into the question itself**.  (There is an "edit" link just below the question which will allow you to do that.)  And I have updated your tags to get rid of [access] (which has, as a description, "DO NOT USE this tag for Microsoft Access, use [ms-access] instead. In computer security, general access control includes identification, authorization, authentication, access approval, and audit.")

Comment: I answered but after re-reading your question my answer is wrong.  You say you have a column called Type with fields called PROD and PROD-OS.  That's wrong.  It looks like maybe your table is "tbl", your field is "Type" and the **values** in the field are PROD and PROD-OS? If that's the case, what do you mean "pull data for both PROD and PROD-OS"?
  Please edit your question to make sense and I'll give it a go.